# How to setup relationship ManyToOne to null in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I need to remove relationship between two objects, but after setup to null on one side, on the second side relationship persists. How can I make this gone also on second side? 
I have Task and User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_task_user_id"))
    private User user;
}
```

Task entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Task> tasks;
}
```

Tests for replace user for task:

```
@Test
public void shouldReplaceUser() throws Exception {
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    TaskService taskService = new TaskService();

    int size = userService.findByTask(6).size();
    System.out.println(userService.findByProcessingTask(6).get(0).getId());
    assertEquals("Incorrect amount of processing users!", 1, size);

    Task task = taskService.findById(6);
    task.setUser(null);
    taskService.save(task);
    Task task = taskService.findById(6);
    System.out.println(userService.findByTask(6).get(0).getId());
    size = userService.findByTask(6).size();
    assertNull("User is not null!", task.getUser());
    //assertEquals("Incorrect amount of users!", 0, size);

    task = taskService.getById(6);
    task.setUser(userService.findById(1));
    taskService.save(task);
    taskDTO = taskService.findById(6);
    System.out.println(userService.findByTask(6).get(0).getId());
    size = userService.findByTask(6).size();
    assertEquals("Incorrect id of user!", Integer.valueOf(1), taskDTO.getUser().getId());
    assertEquals("Incorrect amount of users!", 1, size);
}
```

Initally task is assigned to user with ***id 2***. Next relation should be gone but still when I call method **findByTask** it returns me user with ***id 2***. After assigning user with ***id 1***, still **findByTask** returns user with ***id 2***. When I try to remove task from user collection:

```
Task task = taskService.findById(6);
User user = task.getProcessingUser();
user.getProcessingTasks().remove(task);
userService.save(user);
task.setProcessingUser(null);
taskService.save(task);
```

I get error on line **userService.save(user)**:

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [org.kitodo.data.database.beans.Task#6]

How I can remove user from task but not remove user nor task from database?

**Edit**
Here I have found answer: [JPA OneToMany with Jointable, deleting a link deletes right-side object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057478/jpa-onetomany-with-jointable-deleting-a-link-deletes-right-side-object) - the problem was orphanRemoval equal true.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the Task object from User. All references must be discarded, both ways. Like this:

```
Task task = taskService.findById(6);
User user = task.getUser(); //HERE
user.getTasks().remove(task); //..and HERE
task.setUser(null);
taskService.save(task);
```

Comment: Unfortunately still the same exception but on taskService.save(task). I don't know why there even is deleted object as I don't delete any object from database.